# How do you tell if a site (SPWeb) was unsuccessfully provisioned programmatically?

Tags: 2013, development, provisioning

I have an application that is running periodically using the task scheduler.  The Application gets a list of projects from a database and checks to see if there is a corresponding sub-site in the Project Site Collection.  If not, it provisions the site programmatically.

On more than one occasion, the application has been aborted during the provisioning phase and has left the sub-site in an unknown state.  Programmatically, it looks like the sub-site exists (it shows up in `projectSpSite.OpenWeb(project.number).Exists`), but if someone tries to browse to it, they get a page not found error.

I would like the application to check for these bad sites when it starts.  Does anyone know if there is some flag or property that is set when a site has finished being provisioned?

BTW: I know it is not the best idea to provision sites with an unmonitored application, but this is a requirement that has been forced on me against my will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not direct way to check if site was unsuccessfully provisioned programmatically. For a workaround after successful provisioning of site or in web provisioned event , you can create a web property like "WebProvisioned" and check that property in your code. If it does not exist, delete that site and create again.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I was hoping for some built-in state indicator, but as long as setting the property is my last action before calling spweb.update, I can't see that there is much of a chance of it being in an unknown state.  Thanks!